# How to start Adobe Reader with window maximized?

Tags: windows, pdf, adobe-reader, pdfcreator

I am using Adobe Reader XI on Windows XP. I use PDFCreator to print documents to .pdf files.

I want to have the window maximized whenever I open a .pdf file.

I tried the method in: 
http://blogmines.com/blog/2010/03/08/how-to-automatically-open-a-application-in-a-maximized-window/
but it didn't work. Maybe because I am modifying the shortcut but double clicking on the .pdf file may bypass the shortcut. The AcroRd32.exe application itself doesn't have the maximize window option.

I tried changing the Adobe Reader preferences:
Restore last view settings when reopening documents.
or
Page Display: Default Layout and Zoom.

I also tried changing the settings in PDFCreator:
Page layout.

None of the options explicitly control the maximize window option.

When I open a .pdf file with the default Adobe Reader application, whether the window opens maximized or normal (not maximized) is like a random coin toss. Sometimes it is maximized, sometimes not maximized. It is not consistent.

I wonder if anybody has a simple solution. If not, I think I would have to make do with this strange unpredictability.

I was reading this link:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/3675347

> A second version would be to create a Program Item that does "start
>   /max acrobat.exe" or "start /max acrord32.exe" as appropriate,
>   possibly with path information.

Has anybody done this and could someone explain in detail the steps?

Comment: A "safe" workaround is to use the key sequence [Alt, Space, X] to maximize the window. This saves the effort of aiming the mouse at the blue bar.

Comment: Why do you want it to open maximized? any specific reason?

Answer (score 1):

First of, this solution took some reverse engineering and random spelunking through the very vague resources Adobe gives. Feel free to check the [revision log](https://superuser.com/posts/675674/revisions) for the process that lead me to the solution; as it is quite big for what it's worth I've let it out of the answer.

Now, for the actual solution. Adobe Reader 10.0 in Windows stores it's window settings in these two places in the registry:

```
HKCU\Software\Adobe\Adobe Reader\10.0\SDI\bMaximizeNextDocument
HKCU\Software\Adobe\Adobe Reader\10.0\SDI\bNullDocMaximized
```

The two indicate Adobe to start maximized when opening a file and when opening the program itself (e.g. blank file). However, by setting manually those two values alone to their proper values only works once, because Adobe *wants* to revert back to it's predefined setting (which is to occupy all space on screen in a single regular window)

***Alert: the following involves messing with the Windows Registry. Make a backup beforehand and thread lightly. You may end up messing up your system if you don't take proper precautions. And so on and so on. You have been warned.***

My solution is to **prevent** access to Adobe Reader to those values.
First of, you need to set those values to their proper values before blocking access to the branch. Access `regedit` and navigate to `HKCU\Software\Adobe\Adobe Reader\10.0\SDI\` Here are the before and after values for the relevant keys:

```
bMaximizeNextDocument (0) -> (1)
bNullDocMaximized     (0) -> (1)
```

Right-click the `/SDI/` branch and select *Permissions*. From there press on *Advanced*.

On the *Permissions* tab, select your username and afterwards press the *Edit* button. Check the following checkboxes on the *Deny* side:

- Define value
- Create subkey
- Delete
- Delete DAC
- Owner write

<sub>(I apologize beforehand if any of the terms don't match exactly, as I'm not in an English version of Windows and as such the translation might be off)</sub>

I might be somewhat conservative in the choices but this works. Probably the only key needed to *deny* would be "Define value". After all this is done press *OK*. A warning message might appear, confirm it, and exit `regedit`. Assuming everything is done right, Adobe Reader can no longer return to it's defaults regarding window placement.

Therefore, Adobe Reader will *always* open maximized, regardless of whatever window you happened to put in any session.

Answer (score 0):

I find an answer on below site and i hope this will help others:

HKCU\Software\Adobe\Adobe Acrobt\DC\ExitSection

change bLastExitNormal from 1 to 0

After having done that, Acrobat really remembers its size and its location on my screen!  Both when launching a PDF itself or by the icon of the program

https://www.eehelp.com/question/adobe-acrobat-dc-always-open-maximized-pdf-how-can-i-stop-this/