# How to reset the window position of an application

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Applications that store and restore their absolute window-position, might end up outside the visible screen if the monitor's screen-space changes. This happens for instance when de/attaching an external monitor.

In Windows 7 you can press <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>LEFT</kbd> or <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> etc. to reposition the application when focused.

**What is the easiest way to do this in Windows XP, Windows 2000?**

Comment: In Windows 7 the keys you mention, I see what you mean, they move the window between far left, a restored position, and far right.

In Windows XP or Windows 7, you can click the top left, then a menu appears, click Move. And drag the window. Or you can click the title bar and drag the window from there. But you seem to want a shortcut.. dunno off hand.

Comment: @barlop I am asking for the case where the window's position isn't within the visible screenspace, either due to a bug or due to the change of absolute positions (e.g. switching the primary monitor, switching to a smaller resolution). Additionally, some applications override the default right click menu.

Comment: never tried this but wanna try this? http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/   "Cmdow is a Win32 commandline utility for NT4/2000/XP/2003 that allows windows to be listed, moved, resized, renamed, hidden/unhidden, disabled/enabled, minimized, maximized, restored, activated/inactivated, closed, killed and more."

Comment: the following is far from what you want,but, - tile or cascade windows (right click taskbar..then choose that) though that would do all windows.. but would at least get it on screen in restored form(ie not maximized or minimized).

Comment: @barlop Oh, yes - of course! Please make that an answer. I never use that window-functions, and seem to be oblivious when I need them.

Comment: What applications in XP override the right click menu such that there is no move option? 'cos for Chrome if I right click the chrome icon in the taskbar, I see chrome adds a chrome "task manager" to the menu, but there is still a move option. I can right click then click Move, then use my arrow keys and move it.

Comment: Your comment about windows 7 was Exactly what I needed!!!

Comment: cmdow ...no fun on windows10. Epic fail. `Win` + arrow `left` or `right` still works.

Comment: What about windows 10 for those of us in the modern age? `Win` + `<arrow key>` did nothing.

Comment: @LorenzLoSauer  As to the context when people usually use cascade or tile.. i've sometimes had multiple unsaved notepad windows open ('cos there's often one thing or another that I don't like about a notepad alternative), and I want them all on screen prior to going through them all and saving an/or closing them.  In win7 I shift right click on notepad in the taskbar and click 'side by side' and it puts them all on the screen in what xp would've called tiled.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way is you can right click the taskbar in XP and choose cascade or tile, though it will do it for all windows.

[image]

Another method(which works from an old version like Windows 98, up to a current version like Windows 10), is one could activate the window then do alt-space to bring up the window's menu, then 'M'(which stands for 'move') , and use the arrow keys to move the window more within view

Comment: note that in windows 7, if you shift right click an icon you can tile or cascade just "those" windows, but xp doesn't offer that as far as I can tell(and after 10 years of use!), but you can in XP for all windows, which will at least get your stray one within viewable boundaries on screen.

Comment: Sadly in Windows 10, at least in multi-monitor desktop configurations, a window can be located entirely off the desktop in such a way that cascading won't put it in reach. This sometimes happens with Google Hangouts, for one example.

Comment: @cdaddr  could activate the window  then do alt-space to bring up the window's menu, them 'M' then ENTER, and use the arrow keys to move the window more within view

Comment: yes, or shift-right-click the item on the task bar and choose Move. I don't know about the other way, but if you do it this way the window also gets attached to the mouse pointer and you can mouse it around after you've at least hit an arrow key.

Comment: @cdaddr yeah, seems no enter is needed after the M.. and as soon as you do alt-space, M, then the mouse cursor moves to the title bar, same as the mouse cursor move that happens with the taskbar method you mention.

Comment: another solution would involve nircmd

Comment: I'm glad to confirm that this solution also works for Windows 10.. coworker of mine placed her SIP client (Blink) on her second screen at work and when she came home (where she doesn't have a second screen) she couldn't access it anymore. Pressing ALT-SPACE showed the right-click context menu and after pressing 'Move' she could move the Window back onto her primary display using the arrow keys.

Comment: Im using windows 10, for some reason the notepad now starts outside the screen, the win+left or right does nothing on this case, which is odd... but the alt+space solution fixed my issue, thanks.

Comment: @Yogurtu good that that solved it.. re your window went off screen, i'm not sure.. and i'm still on win7, but maybe it thinks you have a second monitor and somehow it got there . https://superuser.com/questions/1143959/windows-10-detects-too-many-monitors Anyhow how did you even know it was off the screen if you couldn't see it on the screen?

Answer (score 43):

When the window has focus, try ALT+SPACE to open the context menu. There you should see the options which usually include move/minimize/maximize. It should pop up in the visible space even though the window title bar cannot be seen ;)

Comment: Underrated answer. There are times when SHIFT+R-CLICK doesn't work on taskbar (for example, Brave browser), but this one always readily available for anybody. +1!

Comment: @GergelyLukacsy  This is already mentioned in comments by me on my answer on Dec 21 2016 and as I said there, you can do ALT-SPACE then (even if you can't see the menu), you can do M, then move the window. I have now mentioned it in my answer. Another solution involves nircmd

Comment: This method worked great while Windows Key + Arrows did not.

Comment: I'm glad to confirm that this solution also works for Windows 10.. coworker of mine placed her SIP client (Blink) on her second screen at work and when she came home (where she doesn't have a second screen) she couldn't access it anymore. Pressing ALT-SPACE showed the right-click context menu and after pressing 'Move' she could move the Window back onto her primary display using the arrow keys.

Comment: A super elegant one. Thank you!

Comment: You're a life saver!

Answer (score 10):

I've recently answered a question regarding window configurations and ultimately resorted to using the Registry. <s>Although I don't know of any ability like that on XP, standard Move and Dimensioning (right click on the program on the taskbar) seem to not work as expected.</s>

After doing a little digging, try the following:

1. Right click on the program's "icon" on the taskbar.
2. Select Move
3. Use the keyboard arrows to move the window to the position you want.

This should work. The following was something I wrote before that might help you if you want to lock the values.

---

This isn't a one-size fits-all solution, because programs don't follow any naming convention regarding window placement. I'm basing my answer on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/532256/where-is-the-information-about-the-position-of-a-window-stored) but like I said and [researched](https://superuser.com/a/675674/228536), different programs use different keys to store the same information.

---

<sup>(The following is quoted from the first link but as blockquotes make this ugly I retained original formatting)</sup>

For Notepad, this is how you should proceed. In the registry, go to the following folder:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad`

then modify the following values

```
iWindowPosX  
iWindowPosY  
iWindowPosDX  
iWindowPosDY
```

X and Y are the coordinates of the window's top left corner. DX and DY are the width and height of the window.

---

You can conceivably alter the values of your program and afterwards create a backup of the registry keys you changed. That way you would have an automatic way to change the position of your program's window, although you would have to run it whenever you wanted to restore. Or you could see my linked answer and lock those values.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works like a charm. All other methods failed. This works

Comment: best method ever!

Answer (score 5):

In windows 10

1. Close the application
2. Get to know about your application installation path details. (where it is stored under program files, this will help you knowing the structure inside regedit)
3. Open regedit in administrator mode
4. Goto Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Your_software_installation_structure\
   You will see keys for position. like LastXPosition, LastYPosition.
5. Delete both

Now open your application , it will open like as initial opening.

Example : Switching from office to home workplace on VPN with RSA, every time I change my monitor alignment , the RSA software can not be seen (does have maximize option). So i need to delete this to see this RSA in my pc.

regedit: Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\RSA\Software Token\Desktop

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Totally worked for me 5 years later for the same software.

Answer (score 4):

I find the most effective way if the task is showing on the Task bar you Shift+Right click the task and if the "Move" option is greyed out, choose Restore, then Shift+Right Click again and select "Move", then simply tap one of the Arrow keys. This will lock the window to the mouse until you click again. So you can now move the mouse around and wherever the window was it will come to the mouse pointer.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In task bar right click and click on Lock Task bar.
It is just a temp setting. you can revert it back after it is done.
It will move all windows outside the screen to inside.
Then you can move the windows whichever way you want.

Comment: So basically, I unlock and lock the taskbar, and in doing so all window positions will be reset to the current screen space? That would be a great tip.

Answer (score 1):

Double click the "show desktop" button either in the taskbar next to the start button (Windows until XP) or on the right side of the taskbar (since Windows 7) to "pull" all windows to the current desktop.

Comment: Super User is an English-only site, and all the questions and answers must be in English.