# Chrome Developer Inspector disappear while undocked in separated window

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

Since today I don't know how it happen when the Chrome Developer Inspector windows is undocked I cannot view it in any way, it seems hidden.

I have latest Chrome software and Windows 10. I tried also to uninstall Chrome but have the same result. Reboot Windows didn't help too.

Is difficult to explain so I post a screenshot.
This is the situation when developer window is undocked.

[image]

If I click on Developer Window nothing happens.

I tried everything I know but no luck.

Do you have any idea how to reset the position of undocked window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh finally I found a way, it was related to Windows.

I used ALT+SPACE as described in this topic (https://superuser.com/a/1171501/558) and I was able to maximize it again to full screen.